# RewriteRule redirect /pages/view/about to index.php?pages/view/about

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I've created a .httaccess file under my directory "codeIgniter"

I'm trying to redirect
http://www.domain.com/codeIgniter/pages/view/about 
to
http://www.domain.com/codeIgniter/index.php?pages/view/about

my current .httaccess file is

RewriteEngine on +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^codeIgniter/pages/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/codeIgniter/index.php?pages/$1 [L]

but my page is not redirecting. How should i change my .httaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your RewriteRule with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)codeIgniter/pages/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/codeIgniter/index.php?pages/$2 [L]
```

I suspect, the url getting passed has more text at the beginning than just "codeigniter/pages...". The caret symbol (^) signifies the beginning of a string in RegEx.

However, if you are using CodeIgniter, have you looked into just enabling QueryStrings? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html Generally, when using a Framework such as CodeIgniter, you want to embrace MVC, and the custom urls.